# A question about nested indexing of `numpy` arrays

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to understand what the following does at a conceptual level. Let's say we have two `numpy` arrays of random integers

```
arr1

array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 3, 2]])

arr2

array([[1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Then, I do a nested indexing of the second array `arr2` into the first one `arr1`, obtaining

```
arr1[arr2,:]

array([[[1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 1, 1, 3, 2]],

       [[1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2],
        [1, 3, 1, 3, 2]]])
```

which is a new array with shape `(4,8,5)`. It is not clear to me how should I interpret this new object, and how the entries of the two arrays are actually combined together.

Comment: One way of thinking of this operation is that you "replaced" each element of `arr2` with the corresponding row of `arr1'.  Hence the (4,8) shape has expanded to (4,8,5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference on [numpy ndarray indexing with integer arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

---

TLDR:

```
out = arr1[arr2, :]
out[i, j, k] == arr1[ arr2[i, j], k ] # for all valid indices i,j,k
```

Intuition:

The values inside `arr2` are being used independently/separately to index the first axis of `arr1`, and the results are placed into a new array with the same shape as `arr2`.

Comment: much clearer now, but why the shape has an extra dimension?

Comment: Because `arr2` has shape `(4, 8)`, so it defines a subspace with that same shape. The third dimension is resulting from the slice that is used to index the other axis in `arr1` (with shape `(5,)`. Together the result is shape `(4, 8, 5)`.